# Python SWIG bindings with SomeType ** as function argument

Tags: python, c, ffmpeg, swig

I couldn't find any working Python bindings for ffmpeg, so I decided to generate one with SWIG. Generation was quick and easy (no customization, just default SWIG interface), but these a problem using some functions like `int avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext **ps, const char *filename, AVInputFormat *fmt, AVDictionary **options);` from [libavformat/avformat.h](http://svn.perian.org/ffmpeg/libavformat/avformat.h). Using C this can be run simply by:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
int status;
status = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, '/path/to/my/file.ext', NULL, NULL);
```

In Python I try following:

```
>>> from ppmpeg import *
>>> av_register_all()
>>> FormatCtx = AVFormatContext()
>>> FormatCtx
<ppmpeg.AVFormatContext; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'struct AVFormatContext *' at 0x173eed0> >
>>> avformat_open_input(FormatCtx, '/path/to/my/file.ext', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'avformat_open_input', argument 1 of type 'AVFormatContext **'
```

Problem is that Python do not have & equivalent. I tried to use `cpointer.i` and its `pointer_class` (`%pointer_class(AVFormatContext, new_ctx)`), but `new_ctx()` returns pointer and this is not I want definitely. `%pointer_class(AVFormatContext *, new_ctx)` is illegal and gives syntax error. I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention I tried to use typemaps, but don't know how to write custom typemap for struct and documentation has only examples for basic types like int or float...

Comment: How did you get the swig interface file for avformat? Or did you write that yourself?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it's an out parameter. That's necessary in C because C only allows one return value, but Python allows multiple. SWIG lets you mark an argument as OUTPUT or INOUT that should accomplish what you want. See [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Arguments.html#Arguments_nn5).

You can also do it manually with a typemap. A typemap lets you specify an arbitrary conversion.

For example, you likely need `in` and `argout` typemaps as described in the [typemap docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn32).

Note that since you're using custom datatypes you need to make sure that the headers that declare the struct are included in the generated .cpp. If SWIG doesn't take care of this automatically then put something like this at the top of your .i

```
// This block gets copied verbatim into the header area of the generated wrapper.

%{
#include "the_required_header.h"
%}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to mention, I tried to use typemap with `%apply AVFormatContext *OUTPUT {AVFormatContext **ps};` but this have no effect becase SWIG don't know how to handle it `avformat.i:6: Warning 453: Can't apply (AVFormatContext *OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined.` I read documentation and I consider it quite comprehensive, but it do not contain example how to write typemap for struct, only basic C an Python types are covered. Could you provide example of typemap definition for struct? Will update my question.

Comment: @vericule `%apply` is not a typemap. It's like a `#define`. You need a `%typemap`.

Comment: Thanks, I was using `%apply` after `%include typemaps.i` in hope that SWIG has general typemap definition for structs. I was wrong. So basically, I need to write my own typemap. That's a lot of work since ffmpeg structs are quite complex, such struct may contain nested structs and typemap is language-specific. I'm not happy with it, but if it's only way, I guess I have no other choice.